# Contar caracteres repetidos en una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Esta es mi primera publicación les comento
Me colocaron este ejercicio en Python
No tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo

**Escriba una función que cuente la cantidad de caracteres diferentes que aparecen más de una vez en una cadena.
Suponga que todas las cadenas se componen únicamente de letras minúsculas  del alfabeto ingles**

Descripción del retorno
Int **La cantidad de caracteres diferentes  que aparecen repetidos en la cadena**

Esto es lo que llevo pero  no tenga mucha idea que hacer

```
##def contar_caracteres_repetidos(cadena):

print("Ejercio")
print("Caracteres repetidos")

cadena = str(input("Digite la cadena: "))
contador = 0

for letra in cadena:
    for i in letra:
        if letra == (letra):
            contador += 1
print (contador)
```

Ayuda por favor!!

Comment: Cual es tu duda ?

Comment: Como se podría hacer, es que estoy bastante confundido

Comment: también se tienen que contar los espacios o solo las letras por que los espacios también son caracteres

Comment: solo las letras

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo con un diccionario:

```
palabra = 'aabcccdeefg' #Aqui input de la cadena que quieras

letras_dic = dict()  #Guarda repetición de letras
contador = 0 #Caracteres que se repiten

for letra in palabra: #Por cada letra
    if letra in letras_dic: #Si ya estaba en el dic() significa que se repite
        if letras_dic[letra] == 1: 
            contador += 1 #Se agrega al contador
        letras_dic[letra] += 1 #Continua el conteo
    else:
        letras_dic[letra] = 1 #Si la letra no esta en el diccionario, la agrega
    

print(letras_dic)
print(contador)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 2, 'f': 1, 'g': 1}
caracteres repetidos: 3
```

Como puedes observar en la cadena que yo use 'aabcccdeefg' se repite la letra 'a', la 'c' y la 'e', por eso el final output es `3`

Answer (score 1):

Una solución usando una expresión generadora que funciona con cualquier tipo de caracteres:

```
def contar_repetidos(cadena):
    return len(set(x for x in cadena if cadena.count(x) > 1))
```

La expresión recorre los caracteres de la cadena (`for x in cadena`) examinando cuantas veces aparece cada uno (`if cadena.count(x) > 1`) y seleccionando aquellos que lo hace más de una vez.

Una expresión generadora es una comprensión de listas sin los `[]`. Los elementos se van entregando uno a uno sin armar la lista completa.

Los caracteres seleccionados son puestos en un `set` para eliminar los duplicados. El número de elementos en el set es el número de caracteres repetidos en la cadena.

#### Demo

```
def contar_repetidos(cadena):
    return len(set(x for x in cadena if cadena.count(x) > 1))

tests = [
    "",
    "a",
    "abc",
    "abca",
    "abcaaccad"
]

for test in tests:
    print(f"{test} tiene {contar_repetidos(test)} repetidos")
```

produce:

```
 tiene 0 repetidos
a tiene 0 repetidos
abc tiene 0 repetidos
abca tiene 1 repetidos
abcaaccad tiene 2 repetidos

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

hay muchas formas de hacerlo, el tema es si podés usar bibliotecas para simplificar el código.

lo primero es: "Escriba una función" así que como marcaste como comentario es con def:

```
def contar_caracteres_repetidos(cadena):
```

lo segundo: "Suponga que todas las cadenas se componen únicamente de letras minúsculas del alfabeto ingles"

no me gusta suponer así que pasaremos la cadena a minúsculas y obviaremos la "ñ"

y por último: "Descripción del retorno Int La cantidad de caracteres diferentes que aparecen repetidos en la cadena"

Para simplificar o agilizar el código usaré groupby de la biblioteca itertools

```
from itertools import groupby 

def contar_caracteres_repetidos(cadena): # la declaración de la funcíon
    entero = 0
    cadena = sorted(cadena)   #la ordenamos en una lista
    for x,z in groupby(cadena):  #x es el caracter y z el grupo
        if x != "ñ":             #por las dudas haya una "ñ" solo si es distinta 
            if len(list(z)) > 1: #si el largo de la lista grupo mayor que 1
                entero+=1        #incrementamos el contador
    return entero  #retornamos el entero
```

continuamos fuera de la función:

```
print("Ejercicio")
print("Caracteres repetidos")
entrada = input("Digite la cadena: ").lower().replace(" ","")
print(contar_caracteres_repetidos(entrada))
```

fijate que al input no le pongo la función str() input() ya devuelve una cadena,
lo que si hago es pasarla a minúsculas con lower() y reemplazo los espacios para que no los cuente.

y listo!

Answer (score 0):

```
def contar_caracteres_repetidos(cadena:str)->int:
    conteo = 0
    almacenamiento = {}
    for i in cadena:
        if i not in almacenamiento:
            almacenamiento[i] = 1
        else:
            almacenamiento[i] +=1

    for i in almacenamiento:
        if almacenamiento[i] > 1:
            conteo += 1            
    
    return (conteo)
```

Comment: de esta forma lo realice yo, espero sirva de algo

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
def contar_caracteres_repetidos(cadena:str)->int:
    contador = 0
    letra = set(cadena)

    for i in letra:
        if cadena.count(i)>1:
            contador +=1

    return contador
```

Comment: Por favor explica tu respuesta

Comment: Puede que para vos parezca obvio el funcionamiento, pero otros que lleguen a tu respuesta podrían no comprender cómo funciona. Leé [answer], y pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._